# What does Application.CleanString() convert my string to?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm currently trying to take inputs from a table in word, convert the text to numbers, do some basic math on them and then return them to the desired cells.

A typical table looks something like this:[image: Empty table]

I've made the following code (forgive my spaghetti):

```
Sub getRows()

'Counts the number of rows in the given table
    rows_num = Selection.Tables(1).Rows.Count

'Get the values of row 3 -> N, cell 2, 3, 5 and 7 and saves them as a numerical value, ecept for dGVS
    For i = 3 To rows_num
        With Selection.Tables(1).Rows(i)
            TK = Val(Replace(Replace(.Cells(2).Range.Text, ",", "."), "+", ""))
            dOSBL = Val(Replace(.Cells(3).Range.Text, ",", "."))
            dAFRN = Val(Replace(.Cells(5).Range.Text, ",", "."))
            dGVS = .Cells(7).Range.Text
        End With

'Cleans dGVS since I get a special char otherwise
        dGVS = Application.CleanString(dGVS)
        
'Calculates what I need
        kOSBL = TK - dOSBL
        kAFRN = TK - dAFRN
        
'Should check if dGVS is a hyphen and if so set kGVS to the same value, this check does not work
        If dGVS = "-" Then
            kGVS = "-"
        Else
            dGVS = Val(Replace(dGVS, ",", "."))
            kGVS = TK - dGVS
        End If
        
'Returns the calculated values to the desired cells
        With Selection.Tables(1).Rows(i)
            .Cells(4).Range.Text = "+" & kOSBL
            .Cells(6).Range.Text = "+" & kAFRN
            .Cells(8).Range.Text = "+" & kGVS
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

The only problem I seem to encounter is that the if-statement at the bottom doesn't seem to recognize the value of dGVS as a hyphen and therefore, I assume, the check fails and returns the following table:

[image: Filled table]

Does this happen due to the Application.CleanString() or is it another problem entirely? Is there a way to figure out what symbol is actually contained in dGVS to make a proper check, or should I go about this entirely differetly?

A MsgBox print of dGVS returns the following:

[image: MsgBox with contents of dGVS]

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.cleanstring)?

Comment: Yes, and I can't find anywhere where it says it would change the hyphen to anything, but to be sure it wasn't removed, I did the MsgBox print, which shows a hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by checking the character code with AscW(dGVS), which for the used hyphen in this case was 45 and then doing the following check:

```
If AscW(dGVS) = 45 Then
        kGVS = Chr(45)
        Selection.Tables(1).Rows(i).Cells(8).Range.Text = kGVS
    Else
        dGVS = Val(Replace(dGVS, ",", "."))
        kGVS = TK - dGVS
        Selection.Tables(1).Rows(i).Cells(8).Range.Text = "+" & kGVS
End If
```

Thank you [Jonsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17523866/jonsson) for the suggestion.